# Rails - pass @@var to a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.2.3

I need to pass a class variable to a view. For some reason I'm unable to do this.

```
   class HomeController < ApplicationController
      @@user_id = '1343454'
      def index
       #.......................
      end
    def about
       #.......................
      end
    end

    /view/home/about.html.erb
    <% .... 
      @@user_id is not visible 
    ... %>
```

What's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Please refer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575358/class-variables-in-rails-views

Comment: This is hacky, not threadsafe and not recommended. Please don't go this way. If you have a better example on what you *really* want to do, we can help you.

Comment: @ MurifoX, that example is quite complicated. Is there any easier way?

Comment: why are you using @@, to store the current_user id ?

Comment: Because I don't know the right way. What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use `@@`.

In your `application controller` you can define:

```
def current_user
  @current_user.id = '1343454'
end
helper_method :current_user
```

The helper method will make the `current_user` available in any controller or view in your application.

I believe, '1343454' is just an example. Usually we have something like:

```
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```